# AWS Glue and S3 Access Points

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-glue

Is AWS Glue supports S3 Access Point.
Suppose I create IAM Role and assign it to AWS Glue service.
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/create-an-iam-role.html)
And later I want to use this IAM Role in S3 Access point policies.
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points-policies.html#access-points-policy-examples)

Is it supported ?

Comment: Do you mean if you can use the same role to access S3 and run Glue services such as crawlers/jobs etc?

Comment: Yes. If I could specify the same IAM role in S3 Access Point policy.